# Discord.py - Send many changes to the api

Tags: discord.py

### Situation

Let's say there are 200 people in the Voicechannel "Lobby".

We want to start our game night and write !start.
The bot then has to randomly put those people into rooms with a max size of 10.

- Bot has to create 20 Channels
- Bot has to randomly move the 200 People into the 20 Channels.

Easy so far.

### Issue

If we just fire those 220 Requests to the API at the same time, it will not respond to every request.
If we put a thread.sleep 1s between every request, it will take 220 seconds longer.

### Idea

My idea would be to create 10 additional bots which then execute 22 requests each. So everything should be done after 22+x seconds.

Would that be within discords terms of service?
Is there a better way?

Comment: Bad idea, also you cannot create bots within the discord API. I cannot think of a better idea though, using the bot to make the requests altogether would be a bit of API abuse to say the least.

Comment: You can at least reduce the number of API calls by abstracting some of the automation out. For example, you can choose to have x amount of channels already made, but hidden to the users normally unless `!start` is invoked. All you need is one permission API call to make them visible. Same kind of logic can be applied for roles. Have x amount of roles pre-made, assign them randomly, maybe with `asyncio.sleep()` to have some delays.